# Enabling DataAnnotations in full/core platforms of .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I've created a .NET Core (package) library project, which has a class like this:

```
public class Subscriber //: Representation
{
    [Required]
    public SubscriberDef Info;
    public Guid ProviderID;
}
```

No matter what I do, the compiler is not happy with the `[Required]` attribute.  I'm constantly told this:

```
NET Framework 4.5.1 - Not Available
NET Platform 5.4 - Available
```

My project.json initially looked like this:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net451": {
    "dependencies": {
      "WebApi.Hal": "2.6.0",
    }
  },
  "dotnet5.4": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
      "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
      "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
      "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
    }
  }
},
"dependencies": {
  "Excqape": "0.7.0",
  "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.0.11-beta-23516"
}
```

I tried switching the target framework moniker (TFM) from `net451` to `net46`. No luck.  I tried different versions of System.ComponentModel.Annotations being used for both frameworks, still no luck.

What makes this particularly strange is that if I create an ASP.NET Core project, then I am free to have two frameworks where data annotation are respected and will compile:

```
"frameworks": {
  "dnx46": { },
  "dnxcore50": { }
},
```

I figure if data annotations work inside of ASP.NET Core, then assuredly they would work in .NET Core as well?

Am I doing something wrong, or are data annotations truly unavailable for .NET Core fullCLR at this time?

Answer (score 3):

http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=requiredattribute

It is a new platform so first please learn how to search for the NuGet package you need.

Comment: PackageSearch - That's a very useful site that I now know about, thanks!